# Update Entity Framework .edmx from SQL Database project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a Visual Studio solution that has a few projects in it.
One project is based around an Entity Framework model .edmx.
Another project is an SQL Database project.

I can currently 'Update Model from Database...' in the .edmx.
I can also use 'Schema Compare...' in the SQL Database project to update the database.

I would rather not have to push the changes from the SQL Database project to the database, then update the .edmx from the database.

**I would like to update the .edmx from the SQL Database project directly.  Is this possible?**

NOTE: this may not be a great solution having both projects, but it is a legacy product that uses Entity Framework.  At one time, the project was Database First, and the .edmx would follow the changes.  However, we want to track our SQL schema changes with the SQL Database project.  Both projects work well to solve their individual problems, but don't quite work together?